# Excel, MINIF / MAXIF formula

Tags: excel

I am trying to do something similar to a `Averageif` with `max` and `min`.

Current formula :

```
=IF(J15<0,MAX('CS+MS'!C:C),MIN('CS+MS'!C:C))
```

When I'm looking in CS+MS Sheet I want to do something like averageif where I can search column B for a word then return column C.

Is this possble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have OFFICE 365:

```
=IF(J15<0,MAXIFS('CS+MS'!C:C,'CS+MS'!B:B,"SomeString"),MINIFS('CS+MS'!C:C,'CS+MS'!B:B,"SomeString"))
```

IF You have Excel 2010 or later:

```
=IF(J15<0,AGGREGATE(14,7,'CS+MS'!C:C/('CS+MS'!B:B="SomeString"),1),AGGREGATE(15,7,'CS+MS'!C:C/('CS+MS'!B:B="SomeString"),1))
```

If neither use this array formula:

```
=IF(J15<0,MAX(IF('CS+MS'!B:B="SomeString",'CS+MS'!C:C)),MIN(IF('CS+MS'!B:B="SomeString",'CS+MS'!C:C)))
```

Being an array formula one must use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Thanks scott, but what if I want to do max? will this also work the same way? or do I reverse the aggregates?

Comment: The first criteria in the aggregate tell it what it is. `14` is Large and `15` is Small.

Comment: So I would just switch these up in the aggregate function?

Comment: That is the only difference between the two, yes

Answer (score 1):

For ***Microsoft 365*** users can use below formula at one go.

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A1:A6),y,MINIFS(B1:B6,A1:A6,x),CHOOSE({1,2},x,y))
```

[image]